# How to add label to visualization in d3

Tags: d3.js

I would like to label nodes for a graph that I'm reading from a txt file.

```
0,4,-,-,-,-,-,8,-
-,0,8,-,-,-,-,11,-
-,8,0,7,-,-,4,-,2
-,-,7,0,9,-,14,-,-
-,-,-,9,0,-,10,-,-
-,-,4,14,10,0,2,-,-
-,-,-,-,-,2,0,1,6
8,-,-,-,-,-,1,0,7
-,-,2,-,-,-,6,7,0
```

This is the adjacency matrix representation of the following graph
[image]

The rows are a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h and the columns are a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h. I would like to label the nodes of on the graph so that I can validate whether or not the minimum spanning tree is correct. Here is a snippet of the graph
[image]

I am hosting it over at this endpoint https://enigmatic-ocean-25080.herokuapp.com/visualization/. I attempted to add a label to the nodes like so:

```
var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2.5);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return "node: " + d.id; });
```

But the labels aren't showing up. I would love it if someone could help me figure this out. I'd like to use this tool to help other people learn more about graph algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how to do it right:

```
const nodes = svg.selectAll('g.node')
  .data(graph.nodes, d => d.id);

const newNodes = nodes
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('node', true);

newNodes.append('circle')
  .attr('r', 2.5);

newNodes.append('title')
 .text(d => `node: ${d.id}`);
```

Comment: I don't understand why the labels only appear on hover. I'd really like to just have the titles appear on the nodes. Do you have an examples that my show this? Or perhaps you know what needs to be changed to accomplish this?

Comment: Please provide a working snippet or fiddle